# Finding a Kasparov Game

Tags: engines, famous-games, kasparov

I remember seeing a Kasparov game, where Black played a classical bishop sacrifice. He was playing against a computer, and I'm pretty sure it was Deep Junior. I have tried to find this game, but it doesn't seem to be anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2003 [game](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1260279) Kasparov-Deep Junior ) was a draw by repetition. Deep Junior played a bishop sacrifice on h2 and then forced the draw by repetition.

```
[Title "Garry Kasparov-Deep Junior, FIDE Man-Machine WC, New York New York USA, 1/26/2003"]
[FEN ""] 
[startply "19"] 

1. d4 Nf6 2. c4 e6 3. Nc3 Bb4 4. e3 O-O 5. Bd3 d5 6. cxd5 exd5 7. Nge2 Re8 8. O-O Bd6 9. a3 c6 10. Qc2 Bxh2+ 11. Kxh2 Ng4+ 12. Kg3 Qg5 13. f4 Qh5 14. Bd2 Qh2+ 15. Kf3 Qh4 16. Bxh7+ Kh8 17. Ng3 Nh2+ 18. Kf2 Ng4+ 19. Kf3 Nh2+
```